# H2 database 'grant role' error

Tags: sql, h2, ddl

I'm writing some database creation scripts using H2 database but can't grant the roles I create. My script is:

```
create user MY_READWRITEUSER password 'MY_READWRITEUSER';
create user MY_OWNER password 'MY_OWNER' admin ;

create schema MY_OWNER AUTHORIZATION MY_OWNER;
set schema MY_OWNER;

create role MY_READ_ROLE;
create role MY_RW_ROLE;

grant role MY_RW_ROLE to MY_OWNER;
grant role MY_RW_ROLE to MY_READWRITEUSER;

grant role MY_READ_ROLE to MY_READUSER;
```

but when I hit the grant role lines H2 complains:

```
[Error Code: 42001, SQL State: 42001]  Syntax error in SQL statement "GRANT ROLE MY_RW_ROLE[*] TO MY_OWNER "; expected ",, TO"; SQL statement:
```

I don't see any syntax error - what am I doing wrong?

H2 version 1.4.191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the case - if I ask on SO I figure out the answer myself minutes later.

There is a syntax error. This:

```
grant role MY_RW_ROLE to MY_OWNER;
```

should say this:

```
grant MY_RW_ROLE to MY_OWNER;
```